# cURL command works, but Fetch API call returns 200 with 400 validation error in Response Payload

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch-api

Having a huge issue I came across in sending a POST request using Fetch to get a URL shortened.

I am good and able to do a POST request by cURL command to this url shortener API:

Curl command

`curl -d 'api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch' http://fakeurlforexample/api/shorten/`

Response

`{"url": "https://fakeurlforexample/BdzfM3", "long_url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch", "name": "BdzfM3"}`

And I get this great response payload from the API.

But when I do this by [Fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch) with this code I provided below, I get a 200 OK and in the response payload I have a 400 validation error that I am missing the API key.

However, the request payload in the developer console shows that the parameters were passed on properly to the API (I think...)

`{"api_key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","url":"https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch"}`

Here is my code:

`let get_url = 'http://fakeurlforexample.com/api/shorten/';`

```
    let request = new Request(get_url, {
        method: 'POST', 
        body: JSON.stringify({'api_key':'xxxxxxxxx', 'url': 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch'})
    });

    fetch(request)
    .then(function() {
        console.log(request);
        console.log(request.url);
     })
```

Does anyone see the mistake I am making here?

Been beaten down by this for across hours upon hours this week now. Thanks for any help and assistance! And no, I can't easily transition the code to axios as it is right now. This is a demonstration so I'm really just trying to get it to work.

Comment: You are brilliant, thank you for this @DanielBank !!! Let me go try it out!!!

Comment: @DanielBank you saved me from so much more stress over this weekend in getting this up and going for Monday!!! I set it to content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded and changed the parameters into a long string and viola! Thank you!!

Comment: Go ahead and do it :) totally and I will make it the answer! @DanielBank Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [curl manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) Options section on `-d, --data <data>`:

> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form.

Whereas with your request, you are sending a JSON object (Content Type: `application/json`):

```
let request = new Request(get_url, {
  method: 'POST', 
  body: JSON.stringify({'api_key':'xxxxxxxxx', 'url': 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch'})
});
```

Since you know the API endpoint accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` because the curl request succeeds, you can set the content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and send the body as a string:

```
let request = new Request(get_url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}),
  body: 'api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe its because you are defining headers 2 times.

Comment: Updated the code but still getting this same error without any new errors. Thanks though for the reply @İbrahim !